# Python ctypes access violation with const pointer arguments

Tags: python, ctypes

I have an API I'm trying to wrap up in python (2.7.6 on Win7) code using ctypes. Here's the API:

```
CLIENT_DLLFUNC bool CLIENTAPI search_exportToClipCopy(CLIENTHSEARCH handle, int channel, LPCTSTR fileName, const time_t& from, const time_t& to, const bool* cameras, int length, bool usePassword, LPCTSTR password, bool includeTextIn = false, bool excludePlayer = false);
```

The issue I'm having is with the `cameras` argument; and I've had this issue with other const pointer arguments as well. Here's how I'm wrapping this API:

```
def search_exportToClipCopy(self, hSearch, cSearch, fileName, tFrom, tTo, cameras, length, usePassword, password, includeTextIn=True, excludePlayer=False):
    exportToClipCopy = self.sdkdll.search_exportToClipCopy
    exportToClipCopy.argtypes = [c_int, c_int, c_wchar_p, c_long, c_long, POINTER(c_bool), c_int, c_bool, c_wchar_p, c_bool, c_bool]
    exportToClipCopy.restype = c_bool
    exportToClipCopy(hSearch, cSearch, fileName, tFrom, tTo, cameras, length, usePassword, password, includeTextIn, excludePlayer)
```

Unless I'm missing something, I should now be able to call this python function with arguments of the type above, and I will hit the API. But that's not what happens:

```
cam_ptr = pointer(c_bool())
search_exportToClipCopy(hSearch, cSearch, 'dltest.exe', 1399387862, 1399388162, (cam_ptr), 32, False, '', True, False)
```

This is the result:

```
exception: access violation reading 0x5368F802
```

This is one way I've tried it, among a few. I've done the exact same thing with another API from the same client (albeit a different dll), where the argument was a NON-const bool pointer, and all was well. What am I doing wrong?